# From where i can find this <div> tag i want to height equal to 0

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is a line of <div style={height: 50px}> where height is 50px i want to make it 0 in code but where it is located?
index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo2flat.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo1922.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bubblegum+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->

  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

There is a white spacing showing and height was the reason so I want to make it 0. I try to find in different files but i don't know where exactly it is

[image]

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to find react component responsible for that. You may want to use components tab in developer tools to find out which component is responsible for rendering a particular element. link - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en  With that you can  hover on an element and corresponding component gets highlighted.

This looks something like following -
[image]

more information about how to use that - https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/01/02/react-chrome-developer-tools.html

Comment: Thanks Man for the help